# CASE CLAUSE IN WHERE CONDITION

Tags: sql-server, case

I want to create a stored procedure that accepts an optional argument.
I want to accomplish something like the following:

```
CREATE PROC myProc(@myCriteria Int) AS
SELECT myFieldList
FROM myTable
IF @myCriteria IS NOT NULL
WHERE myCriteria = @myCriteria
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep. Breaking into two queries is More efficient if `mycriteria` is indexed for the case a not null value is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
CREATE PROC myProc(@myCriteria Int) AS
SELECT myFieldList
FROM myTable
WHERE (myCriteria = @myCriteria) or (@myCriteria IS NULL and 1=1)
```

Updated with Phillip suggestion

```
CREATE PROC myProc(@myCriteria Int) AS
SELECT myFieldList
FROM myTable
WHERE (@myCriteria is null OR myCriteria = @myCriteria)
```

Comment: WHERE (@myCriteria is null OR myCriteria = @myCriteria) maybe?

Comment: Yeah, it seems so simple now that I look at it. I don't know why I needed help with this. Maybe null was nullifying my thoughts or something.

Comment: @Phillip - It happens, Glad could help you :D